# Change boolean value in QGIS by CASE WHEN

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, boolean

I'm trying to change a field value by the next conditional SQL script from a PostGIS database in QGIS Field Calculator:

```
case
when "Field_1" = 'YES' then "Field_2" = 'True'
else "Field_2" = 'False'
end
```

but it returns `NULL` value.

I've tried with `'t'`and `'true'` as well but it didn't work.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve it?

Comment: Try updating existing field "Field_2" with formula `"Field_1"='YES'`, which will evaluate to true or false. Or change `'True'` to `TRUE` and `'False'` to `FALSE`

Comment: Note that often `'True'` is the literal string "True", whereas `True` is the boolean value of truth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you update a field in QGIS Field calculator, just specify the value, don't `then "Field_2" = something`, just `then something`.

For your code, try :

```
CASE
  WHEN "Field_1" = 'YES' THEN True
  ELSE False
END
```

Comment: If this is a string field, shouldn't it be `'true'` and `'false'` (with single quotation marks)? Or will the expression builder understand `true` and `false` should be used as strings?

Comment: they both worked as I tested them in a boolean virtual field. I guess as you do that if it's a string field `'true'` or `'false'`should come between quotation marks